# Having into Include model using Sequelize.js

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have a problem whith join using sequelize.js. I need a last History date for all users. I'm try this, but something is wrong:

```
this.users.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: History,
            attributes: [
                'value',
                'date'
            ],
            having: { date: [sequelize.fn('MAX', sequelize.col('date')), 'max_date']}
        }
    ]
}
```

This does not work, I wonder if you have any idea how to return this result.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this by `order by` and `limit` , Here you go :

```
this.users.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: History,
            separate : true ,
            order : [['date','desc']] ,
            limit : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: thanks but not works.
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: Please add `user_id` also

Comment: Not works, but my history list  needs a required values in model user. I return all attributes from history and works fine Thanks @VivekDoshi

Comment: @BráulioFigueiredo , Great glad to know that